# How to get queryset ordered by number of intersecting tags with particular object?

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I have Post object with some tags. I need to get queryset of other posts ordered by number of intersecting tags with particular post.

For example there are 4 posts with next tags:

1. *house* *garden* *summer*
2. *garden* plants
3. *summer* *house* conditioning
4. game winter snowballs

So if main post is the first one, sorted queryset should be:

3, 2, 4

Is there the way to do it with django ORM?

Comment: Is `qs1.union(qs2)` useful here? However, I don't know if you can do a union of sliced querysets, and if you can't it's probably far more efficient just to do more than one DB query. Maybe start with a `.count()` of `similar_posts` to see if you need to augment it or not?

Comment: In any context I can think of where you are generating a "final" queryset that will not be further modified, a generator function can be substituted. `yield object` until you have yielded `n_posts` objects, switching from one queryset to another if the first one runs out. No use if you want to allow further filtering.

Comment: @nigel222, I have simplified my question, please look again, maybe it would be easier to solve now

Answer (score 0):

I've handled to write the next function:

```
class Post(models.Model):
...
    def get_similar_posts(self, n_posts):
        posts_tagged_similarly = Post.objects.filter(tags__in=self.tags.all())
        other_posts = Post.objects.exclude(pk__in=posts_tagged_similarly)
        union = posts_tagged_similarly.exclude(pk=self.pk).annotate(n_tags=models.Count('tags')).\
            union(other_posts.annotate(n_tags=models.Value(0, models.IntegerField()))).order_by('-n_tags', '-published')
    return union[:n_posts]
```

It seems scary but it works!